# I want to count the number of specific items

Tags: python

I have this code who handle a list. This is the code:

```
for n in persoane_event:
    split_zi_i = n[1].split('-')
    split_zi_s = n[2].split('-')
    if n[0] == 1 and n[3] != 'L':
        n[3] = 'S1'
        if int(saptamani[0][0]) <= int(split_zi_i[2]) and int(saptamani[0][-1]) >= int(split_zi_s[2]):
            n[3] = 'L'
            print(n)
```

And this is the output that I get from it now:

```
[1, '2020-06-1', '2020-06-1', 'L']
[1, '2020-06-2', '2020-06-2', 'L']
[1, '2020-06-3', '2020-06-3', 'L']
[1, '2020-06-4', '2020-06-4', 'L']
[1, '2020-06-5', '2020-06-5', 'L']
[1, '2020-06-6', '2020-06-6', 'L']
[1, '2020-06-7', '2020-06-7', 'L']
```

As you can see this output it is in a for loop and what I want is to count the total number of `'L'` from this loop. How it is in this case to be like `counter = n[3].count('L')` to `print 7`. Can I do this?
Sorry if it is a dumb question, I just started programming in python 1 month ago.

Comment: You could introduce a counter variable `l_count` and increment it in the if statement that sets the `L` by doing `l_count += 1`

Comment: If you have all that in a list, you could do `len([elt for elt in elements if "L" in elt])`. Inner list isn't even necessary though, as generator expression works fine too.

List comprehensions are powerful, it's good to learn them, as they are pretty idiomatic as well in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer to "Can I do this?" is yes.

The simplest way to do it on your code would be by counting your 'L' assignments:

```
counter = 0
for n in persoane_event:
    split_zi_i = n[1].split('-')
    split_zi_s = n[2].split('-')
    if n[0] == 1 and n[3] != 'L':
       n[3] = 'S1'
       if int(saptamani[0][0]) <= int(split_zi_i[2]) and int(saptamani[0][-1]) >= int(split_zi_s[2]):
           n[3] = 'L'
           counter += 1
print(counter)
```

But I recommend you to check the `len()` function for lists so you would be able to have a simpler code like this:

```
counter = len([n for n in persoane_event if "L" == n[3]])
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `len()` function to determine the length of list, here is an example which may help you,

```
list1 = ['physics', 'chemistry', 'maths']
print (len(list1))

list2 = list(range(5)) #creates list of numbers between 0-4
print (len(list2))
```

output of above example is:

```
3
5
```

you must visit following websites to know the list methods and function in python:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/list_len.htm

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_lists.htm